# When do I know I need to use Cauchy's Integral or Cauchy's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I do not fully understand the concept of each theory as they both look the same to me. When given an integral such as 
$$\int_\Gamma \frac{1}z dz$$

and a path 
$$\Gamma=\{ z:{\mid z-1 \mid=2}\} $$

how do I know which one to use to evaluate the integral?

Comment: Could you be more clear about which theorems you're talking about?

Comment: I was taught them as one being called Cauchy's Integral Formula and the other as Cauchy's Theorem. 
Cauchy's Theorem being the one that says the values of the integral is equal to 0

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem requires your function to be holomorphic on the inside region of your curve. Since $1/z$ is undefined on $0$, which is inside the region delimited by $\Gamma$, you can't actually apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the region includes the origin, and the function $\frac1z$ is not defined there, hence not holomorphic, Cauchy's theorem doesn't apply.

Cauchy's integral formula does though, and the integral equals $2\pi i$...